# get records from two tables

Tags: mysql

This is my first table : fingerprints

```
 Serial UserID  Name            EmpID          CardID   Department     Designation       Status
   1    626242  HariharanJ      626242         626242   IT             Desktop Engineer  Active 
   2    626243  RomiltonA       626243         626243   IT             Desktop Engineer  Active
```

This is my second table : tblemployeepunch

```
  fld_id    fld_date        fld_cardno  fld_mode    fld_punchdatetime
  1         29122011        626242      01          2011-12-29 13:01:00
  2         29122011        626243      01          2011-12-29 13:02:00
  3         29122011        626242      02          2011-12-29 13:30:00
  4         29122011        626243      02          2011-12-29 13:45:00
```

fld_mode 01 means intime 02 means outtime
I need the below output :

```
 Employee_Id    Employee_Name   Department  Day         Punchdate   Intime      Outtime
 626242         HariharanJ      IT          Thursday    2011-12-29  13 : 01     13 : 30
 626243         RomiltonA       IT          Thursday    2011-12-29  13 : 02     13 : 45
```

please help me

Comment: what is the connection between the two tables?

Comment: What did you try and what is the result of your effort?

Comment: Do we have to worry about people checking in on Tuesday and out on Wednesday?  Do we have to worry about people checking in twice and checking out twice on a single day?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem to me...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  On these sites, the way to say 'thanks' is to up-vote helpful answers (when you have enough reputation to do so) and to accept the most helpful answer (a process which also gives you a small boost in your own reputation).  Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially the section [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple Query

Let's make some simplifying assumptions which the sample data satisfies:

- We don't have to worry about people checking in on Tuesday and out on Wednesday;
- We don't have to worry about people checking in twice and checking out twice on a single day;
- We don't have to worry about people signing in but not signing out;
- We don't have to worry about people signig out but not signing in;
- Since the UserID, EmpID and CardID have the same value for each of these users, it doesn't matter which is used to join with the TblEmployeePunch table.

With these assumptions, you can code the query like this:

```
SELECT e.userid                       AS Employee_ID,
       e.name                         AS Employee_Name,
       e.Department                   AS Department,
       DAYOFWEEK(i.fld_punchdatetime) AS Day,
       TIME(i.fld_punchdatetime)      AS InTime,
       TIME(o.fld_punchdatetime)      AS OutTime
  FROM Fingerprints     AS e
  JOIN TblEmployeePunch AS i
    ON e.userid = i.fld_cardno AND i.fld_mode = '01'
  JOIN TblEmployeePunch AS o
    ON e.userid = o.fld_cardno AND o.fld_mode = '02'
 WHERE i.fld_date = o.fld_date;
```

The function names will need validating; the assumption is that DAYOFWEEK() will return a string for the day of the week for a given datetime value passed in.  Similarly, the TIME() function will return the time components of the datetime value passed in.  You may need to specify some extra arguments to get just the hour and minute (rather than including seconds too).

---

## Some people sign in and don't sign out and vice versa

If people are careless (and they are) about signing/punching in and out, then you have people who sign in and don't sign out, and others who sign out and don't sign in.  In the comments, I suggested a FULL OUTER JOIN would solve this; I'm not sure it as good an idea as a 3-way UNION.  The code below is for IBM Informix Dynamic Server (IDS), and was tested on MacOS X 10.7.2 with IDS 11.70.FC2.

I developed the query in stages, which is how I always deal with complex queries like this.

### In and Out

```
SELECT i.Fld_CardNo        AS UserID,
       i.fld_punchdatetime AS i_time,
       o.fld_punchdatetime AS o_time
  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
  JOIN TblEmployeePunch AS o
    ON o.Fld_CardNo = i.Fld_CardNo AND i.Fld_Date = o.Fld_Date
 WHERE i.fld_mode = '01' AND o.fld_mode = '02';
```

#### Results

```
 userid     i_time  o_time
 626242     2011-12-29 13:01:00     2011-12-29 13:30:00
 626243     2011-12-29 13:02:00     2011-12-29 13:45:00
```

### In only

```
SELECT i.Fld_Cardno        AS UserID,
       i.Fld_PunchDateTime AS i_time,
       CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) AS o_time
  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS o
         WHERE o.Fld_Cardno = i.Fld_Cardno
           AND o.Fld_Date   = i.Fld_Date
           AND o.Fld_Mode   = '02'
       )
   AND i.fld_mode = '01';
```

#### Results

```
 userid     i_time                  o_time
 626247     2011-12-29 10:15:00
```

### Out only

```
SELECT o.Fld_Cardno        AS UserID,
       CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) AS i_time,
       o.Fld_PunchDateTime AS o_time
  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS o
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
         WHERE i.Fld_Cardno = o.Fld_Cardno
           AND i.Fld_Date   = o.Fld_Date
           AND i.Fld_Mode   = '01'
       )
   AND o.fld_mode = '02';
```

#### Results

```
 userid     i_time                  o_time
 626248                             2011-12-29 11:05:00
```

### 3-way UNION for 'in and out', 'in only' and 'out only'

```
SELECT i.Fld_CardNo        AS UserID,
       i.fld_punchdatetime AS i_time,
       o.fld_punchdatetime AS o_time
  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
  JOIN TblEmployeePunch AS o
    ON o.Fld_CardNo = i.Fld_CardNo AND i.Fld_Date = o.Fld_Date
 WHERE i.fld_mode = '01' AND o.fld_mode = '02'
UNION
SELECT i.Fld_Cardno        AS UserID,
       i.Fld_PunchDateTime AS i_time,
       CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) AS o_time
  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS o
         WHERE o.Fld_Cardno = i.Fld_Cardno
           AND o.Fld_Date   = i.Fld_Date
           AND o.Fld_Mode   = '02'
       )
   AND i.fld_mode = '01'
UNION
SELECT o.Fld_Cardno        AS UserID,
       CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) AS i_time,
       o.Fld_PunchDateTime AS o_time
  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS o
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
         WHERE i.Fld_Cardno = o.Fld_Cardno
           AND i.Fld_Date   = o.Fld_Date
           AND i.Fld_Mode   = '01'
       )
   AND o.fld_mode = '02';
```

#### Results

```
 userid     i_time  o_time
 626242     2011-12-29 13:01:00     2011-12-29 13:30:00
 626243     2011-12-29 13:02:00     2011-12-29 13:45:00
 626247     2011-12-29 10:15:00                   
 626248                             2011-12-29 11:05:00
```

## Final Query

Joining the 3-way UNION with the Fingerprints table yields:

```
SELECT e.userid            AS Employee_ID,
       e.name              AS Employee_Name,
       e.Department        AS Department,
       DAYOFWEEK(t.i_time) AS Day,
       TIME(t.i_time)      AS InTime,
       TIME(t.o_time)      AS OutTime
  FROM Fingerprints AS e
  JOIN (SELECT i.Fld_CardNo        AS UserID,
               i.fld_punchdatetime AS i_time,
               o.fld_punchdatetime AS o_time
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
          JOIN TblEmployeePunch AS o
            ON o.Fld_CardNo = i.Fld_CardNo AND i.Fld_Date = o.Fld_Date
         WHERE i.fld_mode = '01' AND o.fld_mode = '02'
        UNION
        SELECT i.Fld_Cardno        AS UserID,
               i.Fld_PunchDateTime AS i_time,
               CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) AS o_time
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS o
                 WHERE o.Fld_Cardno = i.Fld_Cardno
                   AND o.Fld_Date   = i.Fld_Date
                   AND o.Fld_Mode   = '02'
               )
           AND i.fld_mode = '01'
        UNION
        SELECT o.Fld_Cardno        AS UserID,
               CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) AS i_time,
               o.Fld_PunchDateTime AS o_time
          FROM TblEmployeePunch AS o
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                  FROM TblEmployeePunch AS i
                 WHERE i.Fld_Cardno = o.Fld_Cardno
                   AND i.Fld_Date   = o.Fld_Date
                   AND i.Fld_Mode   = '01'
               )
           AND o.fld_mode = '02'
       ) AS t
    ON e.userid = t.userid
 ORDER BY e.userid;
```

#### Final data

```
 employee_id   employee_name   department   day        intime     outtime
 626242        HariharanJ      IT           Thursday   13:01:00   13:30:00
 626243        RomiltonA       IT           Thursday   13:02:00   13:45:00
 626247        InnerJ          IS           Thursday   10:15:00        
 626248        OuterJ          IS                                 11:05:00
```

Oh, fiddlesticks: the day of the week comes out null when the `intime` is null.  That can be fixed; I'm leaving it as an exercise for the reader.  (*Hint*: COALESCE() or NVL() or IFNULL() will probably figure in the answer.)

---

### Support Information

#### Fingerprints Table and Data

```
CREATE TABLE Fingerprints
(
    Serial      SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID      INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Name        CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    EmpID       INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CardID      INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Department  CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Designation CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Status      CHAR(8) NOT NULL CHECK(Status IN ('Active', 'Inactive'))
);

INSERT INTO Fingerprints VALUES(1, 626242, "HariharanJ", 626242, 626242, "IT", "Desktop Engineer", "Active");
INSERT INTO Fingerprints VALUES(2, 626243, "RomiltonA",  626243, 626243, "IT", "Desktop Engineer", "Active");
INSERT INTO Fingerprints VALUES(3, 626247, "InnerJ",     626247, 626247, "IS", "Web Technician",   "Active");
INSERT INTO Fingerprints VALUES(4, 626248, "OuterJ",     626248, 626248, "IS", "Web Technician",   "Active");
```

#### TblEmployeePunch Table and Data

```
CREATE TABLE TblEmployeePunch
(
    Fld_ID              SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Fld_Date            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Fld_CardNo          INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Fingerprints(UserID),
    Fld_Mode            CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Fld_PunchDateTime   DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TblEmployeePunch VALUES(1, 29122011, 626242, "01", "2011-12-29 13:01:00");
INSERT INTO TblEmployeePunch VALUES(2, 29122011, 626243, "01", "2011-12-29 13:02:00");
INSERT INTO TblEmployeePunch VALUES(3, 29122011, 626242, "02", "2011-12-29 13:30:00");
INSERT INTO TblEmployeePunch VALUES(4, 29122011, 626243, "02", "2011-12-29 13:45:00");
INSERT INTO TblEmployeePunch VALUES(5, 29122011, 626247, "01", "2011-12-29 10:15:00");
INSERT INTO TblEmployeePunch VALUES(6, 29122011, 626248, "02", "2011-12-29 11:05:00");
```

#### DayOfWeek Function

Informix doesn't provide an internationalized DAYOFWEEK function, so here is a substitute (also not internationalized).  It would probably be possible to write an internationalized version using TO_DATE() and an appropriate format string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DayOfWeek(d DATE) RETURNING CHAR(9);
    DEFINE dow INTEGER;
    LET dow = WEEKDAY(d);
    IF dow = 0 THEN RETURN "Sunday";    END IF;
    IF dow = 1 THEN RETURN "Monday";    END IF;
    IF dow = 2 THEN RETURN "Tuesday";   END IF;
    IF dow = 3 THEN RETURN "Wednesday"; END IF;
    IF dow = 4 THEN RETURN "Thursday";  END IF;
    IF dow = 5 THEN RETURN "Friday";    END IF;
    IF dow = 6 THEN RETURN "Saturday";  END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END PROCEDURE;
```

#### TIME

Informix uses a set of types such as DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND instead of TIMESTAMP and DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND instead of TIME.  This function converts a 'TIMESTAMP' to 'TIME'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Time(dt DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) RETURNING DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND;
    RETURN EXTEND(dt, HOUR TO SECOND);
END PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that the customary way of saying 'Thank You' on these sites is to up-vote the answers that help (if you have enough reputation to do so), and to accept the most helpful answer (which you can always do).  See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information about this.  Note that accepting an answer benefits you a little to.

Comment: If Employee does’nt access While punch in or punchout. 

Intime  = NULL
Outtime = NULL

Comment: If Employee does’nt access While Punchin or out.The coding should state as  mentioned below.

InTime = NULL (or)
OutTime = NULL

Comment: That makes life messy - very messy.  You need a FULL OUTER JOIN between the two references to the TblEmployeePunch table, with a COALESCE() or equivalent for the two employee ID values.  Of course, the fact that MySQL does not support a FULL OUTER JOIN only complicates matters; you have to form the UNION of a pair of LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN queries (but at least you don't have to worry about the COALESCE any more).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .But i can't understand Because am new for mysql. Please send the exact code to me.

Comment: Hi Just now i got an error from the above query. I was use some select  fields like 'DATE_FORMAT(t.i_time ,'%d-%m-%y') as punchdate,
       DAYNAME(t.i_time) AS Day' in the above select statement it give only intime punchdate and dayname. Suppose i ill insert only outime  means punchdate and dayname doesn't display. what i do ?

Comment: Break what you've written down into component pieces, run each one in isolation, see whether the result is what is expected. There are the three queries in the UNION; each can be run in isolation.  Then the UNION as a whole; then the result. There might be a typo in my code; there might be a typo in yours; there might be a bug in my code (though I showed what I got as results with the data also shown above; that will help you verify); or there might be a bug in MySQL. With all due respect, I suspect the typo is in your code, or there's a logic bug in mine despite the test; blame the DBMS last!